# TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-tesseract

I am trying to use tesseract-OCR to print text from the image. But I am getting the above error. I have installed tesseract OCR using https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki and pytesseract in the anaconda prompt using pip install pytesseract but its not working. Please help if anyone has faced the similar issue.

```
Collecting pytesseract
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/56/befaafbabb36c03e4fdbb3fea854e0aea294039308a93daf6876bf7a8d6b/pytesseract-0.2.4.tar.gz (169kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 174kB 288kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\500066016\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytesseract) (5.1.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pytesseract
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pytesseract ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\500066016\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\a8\0c\00\32e4957a46128bea34fda60b8b01a8755986415cbab3ed8e38
Successfully built pytesseract
```

Below is the code:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np

def get_string(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
    dilate = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    erosion = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

    cv2.imwrite('removed_noise.jpg', img)
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    cv2.imwrite('thresh.jpg', img)
    res = pytesseract.image_to_string('thesh.jpg')
    return res
print('Getting string from the image')
print(get_string('quotes.jpg'))
```

Below is the error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-cf6e0fca14b4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/500066016/.spyder-py3/project1.py', wdir='C:/Users/500066016/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\500066016\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\500066016\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/500066016/.spyder-py3/project1.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(get_string('quotes.jpg'))

  File "C:/Users/500066016/.spyder-py3/project1.py", line 20, in get_string
    res = pytesseract.image_to_string('thesh.jpg')

  File "C:\Users\500066016\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 294, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(*args)

  File "C:\Users\500066016\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 202, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\500066016\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 172, in run_tesseract
    raise TesseractNotFoundError()

TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path```
````

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Step 1: Download and install Tesseract OCR from this [link](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v4.1.0-bibtag19.exe).

Step 2: After installing find the "**Tesseract-OCR**" folder, double Click on this folder and find the **tesseract.exe**.

Step 3: After finding the **tesseract.exe**, copy the file location.

Step 4: Pass this location into your code like this

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
```

Note: C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe == your copied location

Comment: wow, work like charm, and i don't even need to add PATH, thank you.

Comment: This is the source folder from the Step 1: https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/ .
You might find there the newer versions of Tesseract OCR.

Answer (score 3):

You should to install :

```
! apt install tesseract-ocr
! apt install libtesseract-dev
```

And

```
! pip install Pillow
! pip install pytesseract

import pytesseract
from PIL import ImageEnhance, ImageFilter, Image
```

I have code on Cola from google drive to run. Below of my example code:

I took any example picture of text on website

Step 1: import some packages

```
import pytesseract
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
```

Step 2 : Upload file of text.png on Colab

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()

current browser session. Please rerun this cell to enable.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MessageError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-21dc3c638f66> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import files
----> 2 uploaded = files.upload()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/colab/_message.py in read_reply_from_input(message_id, timeout_sec)
    104         reply.get('colab_msg_id') == message_id):
    105       if 'error' in reply:
--> 106         raise MessageError(reply['error'])
    107       return reply.get('data', None)
    108 
MessageError: TypeError: Cannot read property '_uploadFiles' of undefined
```

-> Don't worry, please run code again it will accept it. And then, you could choose which if you want to upload

Step 3 :

- read the image using OpenCV

  image = cv2.imread("text.png")
- or you can use Pillow

  image = Image.open("text.png")
- check it. Have they show file text picture.

  image

get the string

```
string = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
```

print it

```
print(string)
```

Done.